# Best practice for fetchING a unique Model in a View using BackBone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following scenario:

> **Item Grid** > **Select one** Item from Grid > Open a **view with `Item Detail`**.

**Which is the best practice for initialize the `ItemDetail` Model and store it in variable**?

- Store in some global var and reset every ItemDetail `fetch`?
- Store in some `ItemDetailView` variable?

Snippet:

```
app.ItemDetailView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(id){
        app.ItemDetailInstance = new ItemDetail(id);
        //OR
        this.itemDetail = new ItemDetail(id);

        //fetch
    }
}
```

Comment: You should avoid globals whenever possible.

Comment: Is local itemDetail right?

Comment: It's definitely best to keep the model local to the view, but then again, it really depends on your overall app implementation details.

Comment: If you consider the views on the page as a hierarchy, then normally there is a view at the right level to have it's `this.model` set to the selected model in this case. You obviously want to use this model in several places, if that usage isn't possible without setting a global, then maybe you should reconsider the way you access it.

Comment: I'll consider the `this.model` option... someone write an answer and I'll check as right

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a Backbone collection in order to fetch all your Items?

Problem with Backbone is there is no really good practices since you're totally free about your architecture. But I think that you should fetch model before creating the ItemDetailView.

If you use a collection:

```
app.listItemsView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        // You fetch the collection once
        // This collection contain all items models 
        this.collection = collection.fetch();
    },

    onItemClick: function(id) {
        // Get the id or cid of a specific item 
        var model = this.collection.get(id);
        // Model object already contain data of the model
        var view = new ItemDetailsView({model: model});
    }
})
```

This is a basic use of collection and models.
If you can fetch a global collection that contain all your model, you can only fetch it once, and then play with views.

Comment: While I agree with the start of your answer, the code example is wrong and it's not really a solution about when to fetch a specific model, which will happen even when fetching a collection. Most of the time, a collection receives a simplified version of each object. A specific model fetch will return the full object with nested data (if necessary).

Comment: Also, note that the `fetch` function doesn't return the collection or model. It returns a [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) object. And Backbone views expect an options object as an argument, not a model instance. It should be `ItemDetailsView({ model: model })`.

Comment: @Lucas The code sample given in this answer has some errors as mentioned in comments above, but the idea is correct. Your item grid  should be based on a collection of models. You should just pass the selected model into item view. You can fetch the model inside the view if you have an API that returns more specific details of that model. This is the ideal scenario in backbone.